# Getting setup version in asp.net website project

Tags: c#, asp.net, setup-deployment

I have an **ASP.NET project** that contains a **Web Deployment project** (to compile the website) and a **Setup project** (that creates the Setup and install the compiled version of the website).

I always change the **application version** on the **Setup Project** and I want to be able to reference that version number into the Website itself but without creating an entry in the web.config with the version number (not today, but I think that in the future I will forgot to change the version number in the web.config)

Is there any trick that I can use to get this behaviour?

Just like using the App.Config in *WinForms* using just:

```
Version vrs = new Version(Application.ProductVersion);
myVersionLabel.Text = "Major: " + vrs.Major + " Minor: " + vrs.Minor;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do a custom action that writes/updated the setup version to your web.config. No worries about forgetting to do that manually.
EDIT:
I made a blog post about how to do this. Take a [look here](http://insomniacgeek.com/blog/how-to-determine-setup-version-from-within-an-asp-net-page/).

Comment: any idea on how do I accomplish that?

Comment: I just made a blog post about how to do that, see my edit notes in my answer above. Hope it helps.

Comment: just to add: with the free version of Jing (www.jingproject.com) you could create a nice tutorial for this, I know it will help a lot of guys like me ;)